# How to join two 2D objects into one?

Tags: objects, edges

I want to join heart into plane. Both meshes are 2D (0 value in Y axis). I know that i could join one by one edges with alt+M but i have heck of A LOT EDGES, it would take ages to finish. How can i merge those two objects to be connected with edges. Thanks for all effort to help me.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Select the plane, then the heart and press **Ctrl+J**.

Comment: I need them to be connected with edges. I already made them to be as one object. My bad in question i said "object" now i fixed it. Theres one object with two meshes and those meshes need to be connected with edges.

Comment: Split the objects, extrude the heart through the plane and then use boolean/knife modifier?

Answer (score 2):

First apply transformations to your objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Loc, Rot&Scale*). Select your heart mesh, then the plane in *Object Mode*, then enter the *Edit Mode* of the plane, press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type ***Knife Project***. Extrude the plane a bit and give it a ***Remesh Modifier*** being in *Object Mode*. Apply the modifier, then delete extruded vertices. Finally join meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Correct some vertices position (merge them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>).
[image]